# $\inf$ and $\sup$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $A, B$ are non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, with the following property: $$\forall x\in A, y\in B, x\le y,$$ and $B$ is bounded above. Show that $\sup A \le \inf B$.

We have that $A$ is bounded above and $B$ is bounded below, and any element $x$ of $A$ is a lower bound of $B$, and each $y$ in $B$ is a upper bound of $A$. But I cant go on from here.

Comment: **Hint:** All you need to do is show that $\inf B$ is an upper bound of $A$.

Comment: Nit-pick: $A$ and $B$ must be non-empty.

Comment: I corrected this, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $B$ is contained in the set $U(A)$ of upper bounds of $A$. Therefore
$$
\inf B\ge\inf U(A)=\min U(A)=\sup A
$$
Here I use the property that if $X\subseteq Y$ and both sets are lower bounded, then $\inf X\ge\inf Y$.

*Proof.* $\inf X$ is the greatest lower bound of $X$; every lower bound of $Y$ is also a lower bound of $X$, so the greatest lower bound of $Y$ is a lower bound of $X$. This means that $\inf Y\le\inf X$.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a mildly interesting way to get the answer.

Choose any two points $x_0 \in A$ and $y_0 \in B$. To find the $\sup$ and $\inf$, we can assume that both $A$ and $B$ are contained in the closed interval $K =  [x_0, y_0]$ (a singleton interval is OK here).

The intersection of any finite number of closed intervals of the form $[x, y]$ with $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ is another non-empty closed interval with the left endpoint in $A$ and the right endpoint in $B$. Since $K$ is compact, the intersection of all these closed sets is a non empty closed set, and it would have to also be a closed interval, say,

$[a, b]$

If $c \in [a, b]$ then $\sup A \le c \le \inf B$. 
Proof: Since $c$ belong to every interval $[x,y]$, it is both an upper bound of $A$
 and a lower bound of $B$.

For extra credit show that 
$\sup A = a $
and 
$\inf B = b $

Note: The only requirements here are 
$A \ne \emptyset$
$B \ne \emptyset$
$\forall (x\in A, y\in B), \, x\le y$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\beta = \inf B$ and $ \alpha=\sup A$.

We have that $x \le \beta$ for all $x\in A$. In fact, if there's a $x_0\in A$ such that $\beta < x_0$, then $x_0$ would be a lower bound of $B$ greater than $\beta$, which is absurd.

Then if $\beta < \alpha$, $\beta$ would be a upper bound of $A$ lower than $\alpha$, which is absurd. Hence we must have $\alpha \le \beta.$

Answer (score 1):

$A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$

$\forall x\in A, y \in B$,  $x \le y$.

$A$ is bounded  above : $\sup (A)$ exists.

$B$ is bounded below: $\inf (B)$ exists.

1)There exists a sequence $x_n \in A , n\in \mathbb{N},$ with

$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \sup(A)$.

2)There exists a sequence $y_n \in B , n\in \mathbb{N},$ with

$\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = \inf(B)$.

Since $x_n \le y_n$,  $n \in \mathbb{N},$ we have

$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \le \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$,

$\sup(A) \le \inf(B)$.

Comment: You can write `\sup` and `\inf` to get $\sup$ and $\inf$.

Comment: @md2perpe. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction. Let $a=\sup(A)$ and $b=\inf(B)$. Suppose $a>b$. We know that $A\cap (a-\epsilon,a]\neq\emptyset~~~\forall\epsilon>0$ and $B\cap[b,b+\epsilon)\neq\emptyset~~~\forall\epsilon>0$. Since $a>b$ this means that we can choose $\epsilon$'s such that $B\cap[b,\beta)\neq\emptyset$ and $A\cap(\alpha,a]\neq\emptyset$ where $\beta<\alpha$. Thus, there exists $x\in B:x< \beta$ and $y\in A:y>\alpha$. Hence, $x<\beta<\alpha<y$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Suggestion: Get rid of $\varepsilon$!$\;$
If $a \gt b$ set $\gamma = .5 (a + b)$.
Select $x \in A \cap (\gamma,a]$ and $y \in B \cap [b, \gamma)$ so that  $x \gt \gamma \gt y$. Contradiction.

Comment: I put in the changes for you.

Comment: @MikeMathMan: If you have an alternate argument, you can post it as your own answer rather than suggesting an edit on someone else's.

Comment: @MikeMathMan I appreciate the approach that you have, but my answer is as intended. I wanted to establish the $\epsilon$ part so that the OP knows what theorem I am using.

Comment: @er it was not intended to be an alternate argument, but a streamlined improvement. But OK.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\sup(A)$ and $b=\inf(B)$. Suppose $a \gt b$. 
Set $\gamma = .5 (a + b)$.
Select $x \in A \cap (\gamma,a]$ and $y \in B \cap [b, \gamma)$ so that  $x \gt \gamma \gt y$.
This is a contradiction.